# TensorFlow: are all the basic operations in python overidden in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to tensorflow, and trying to write loss function(squared loss) using basic python operators, but it is not working. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong. Thanks in adavnce

```
n = x_data.shape[0]
L = (Y_pred-y)**2
loss = (1/n)*tf.reduce_sum(L)
```

I get loss=0.0 when I run the corresponding session

```
_ ,_m, _c, _l = session.run([optimizer,m,c,loss], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data})
```

y is a placeholder

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y_pred,y))
```

this works just fine?

Complete Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#downloading dataset
!wget -nv -O /resources/data/PierceCricketData.csv https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/reyjo1hk43m2x79nreywwfwcdd5yi8zu.csv


df = pd.read_csv("/resources/data/PierceCricketData.csv")
df.head()

%matplotlib inline

x_data, y_data = (df["Chirps"].values,df["Temp"].values)

plt.plot(x_data, y_data, 'ro')
# label the axis
plt.xlabel("# Chirps per 15 sec")
plt.ylabel("Temp in Farenhiet")


x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=x_data.shape)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=y_data.shape)
m = tf.Variable(3.0, name='m')
c = tf.Variable(2.0, name='c')

Y_pred = m*x+c



n = x_data.shape[0]
L = (Y_pred*nf-y*nf)**2
loss = (1/n)*tf.reduce_sum(L)

# loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y_pred,y))


optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)

session = tf.Session()
session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

convergenceTolerance = 0.0001
previous_m = np.inf
previous_c = np.inf

steps = {}
steps['m'] = []
steps['c'] = []

losses=[]

for k in range(100000):
    _ ,_m, _c, _l = session.run([optimizer,m,c,loss], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data})



    steps['m'].append(_m)
    steps['c'].append(_c)
    losses.append(_l)
    if (np.abs(previous_m - _m) <= convergenceTolerance) or (np.abs(previous_c - _c) <= convergenceTolerance):

        print "Finished by Convergence Criterion"
        print k
        print _l
        break
    previous_m = _m, 
    previous_c = _c, 
print(losses)
```

Output I get is [0.0, 0.0]
Why?

Comment: What do you mean its not working? Be specific, and include any error messages you get.

Comment: I get loss=0.0 when I run the corresponding session

     _ ,_m, _c, _l = session.run([optimizer,m,c,loss], feed_dict={x: x_data, y: y_data})

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to say if that is a problem or it is right. Please include more code and information.

Comment: I updated the question with the complete code, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official TensorFlow implementation of mean_squared_error :

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops, math_ops
@tf_export("losses.mean_squared_error")
def mean_squared_error(labels, predictions, weights=1.0, scope=None,
                       loss_collection=ops.GraphKeys.LOSSES, 
                       reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS):
    if labels is None:
        raise ValueError("labels must not be None.")
    if predictions is None:
        raise ValueError("predictions must not be None.")
    with ops.name_scope(scope, "mean_squared_error",(predictions, labels, weights)) as scope:
        predictions = math_ops.to_float(predictions)
        labels = math_ops.to_float(labels)
        predictions.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
        losses = math_ops.squared_difference(predictions, labels)
        return compute_weighted_loss(losses, weights, scope, loss_collection, reduction=reduction)
```

As you can see in their source code you should make sure that the tensors have the same dtype. Hope that answers your question.